# How to allocate total amount to detail

Tags: r

There are dataframe `detail` and `total` ,how to allocate total `amount` in`total` to detail and create new column as `amount_allocate_from_total`?
The `result` as the image attached .

```
detail <- data.frame(cagetory=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c"),
                       amount=c(1,3,7,2,1,4,6,1,6))

total <- data.frame(cagetory=c("a","b","c"),
                     amount=c(20,10,9))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image it seems you want to subtract `amount` in total with `sum` of all values in `detail` except the last one for each `cagetory` and place it in the last row.

Here's a `dplyr` option.

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(detail, total, by = 'cagetory') %>%
  group_by(cagetory) %>%
  mutate(amount_allocate_from_total = 
         replace(amount.x, n(), last(amount.y) - sum(amount.x[-n()]))) %>%
  ungroup

# cagetory amount.x amount.y amount_allocate_from_total
#  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>                      <dbl>
#1 a               1       20                          1
#2 a               3       20                          3
#3 a               7       20                         16
#4 b               2       10                          2
#5 b               1       10                          1
#6 b               4       10                          4
#7 b               6       10                          3
#8 c               1        9                          1
#9 c               6        9                          8
```

Comment: that's great .Thanks for you help!